# BT.1120 Video Standard Specifications?

Tags: video-quality, video-standards, specifications

I have a camera that states this under the video output specification.

Ive tried finding out what it means but can't does anyknow know ?

Comment: this is my question, when i signed up here, the facebook didnt work and created a new account rather than linking it to my existing stack accounts.

Answer (score 1):

This is a document from the ITU :

http://www.itu.int/rec/R-REC-BT.1120-8-201201-I/en

that specifies Digital interfaces for HDTV studio signals.
This kind of signal is commonly carried on an HD-SDI physical layer.